# Access attributes on objects inside ruby objects

Tags: ruby, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I'm building a `LineItemGenerator` object whose purpose is to generate an array of attribute values given the desired attributes.

The problem is the given object has objects as attributes. So the "attributes" given are really "nested attributes".

The goal is to access the requested nested attributes from `item`, in this case `item.name` and `item.style.name` by creating some input data structure and using some algorithm.

Currently, I'm representing my "nested attributes" input data structure as an array of arrays, `nested_attributes`

My algorithm that's doing the heavy lifting is called `#generate`.

It takes the original `item` and the `nested_attributes`. Next, it maps over the `nested_attributes`, reducing each `nested_attribute` into an "attribute" by `send`ing messages to the original `item` on each iteration.

```
class Style
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize name:
    @name = name
  end
end

class Item
  attr_reader :name, :style
  def initialize name:, style:
    @name = name
    @style = style
  end
end

class LineItemGenerator
  def generate item:, nested_attributes:
    nested_attributes.map do |nested_attribute|
      nested_attribute.reduce(item) do |obj, attribute| # <-- algorithm using #reduce to burrow in
        obj.send(attribute)
      end
    end
  end
end


require 'minitest/autorun'

class SomeTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_it_returns_the_right_line_item
    style = Style.new name: 'cool'
    item = Item.new name: 'pants', style: style

    # input data structure is array or arrays
    nested_attributes = [[:name], [:style, :name]]
    input = { item: item, nested_attributes: nested_attributes}
    output = LineItemGenerator.new.generate input
    assert_equal ['pants', 'cool'], output
  end
end
```

I'm curious about new ways to implement my input data structure and algorithm that are more declarative and expressive. Both sections of interest are called out in the comments above.

It feels weird to use `#inject` because I'm really just trying to chain together a variable number of `send` calls. For example:

```
item = Item.new name: 'pants', style: Style.new(name: 'cool')
p item.send(:style).send(:name) #=> "cool"
```

Is there some [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) method that would be a better choice in this case? Is there a better choice for my input data structure?

Comment: No answers after two hours to a pure-Ruby question probably means that readers don't understand it. You are effectively saying, "study my code to understand the question". That will not generate interest. You must be more precise in stating your question. An example would probably help a lot. If you give one, ensure that all data are valid Ruby objects (e.g., no  `[1,2,3...]`), assign a variable to each input object (`a = [1,2,3]`), so readers can cut and paste your code and refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them, and show your desired result.

Comment: It also could mean it's Saturday :). Please see edit and included test. Is this helping clarify?

Comment: What's your use case for this problem? How many types of objects can be a `line_item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells more like a software design problem to me, so this is how I would approach it from a design perspective.

- Reason from the perspective of one component at a time.
- Separate what we're trying to communicate from how it will be implemented

---

> The `LineItemGenerator`'s job is to generate an array of attribute values for an item given the desired attributes.

Based on that, a `LineItemGenerator`:

- takes an item with attributes
- implements `generate_attribute_values` given a list of desired attributes

This might look like:

```
LineItemGenerator.new(@item).generate_attribute_values(:name, :style)
```

I'd remove `generate` as it doesn't seem to be the right word here. We're just retrieving and filtering existing values, not creating a new attribute value object.

```
LineItemGenerator.new(@item).attribute_values(:name, :style)
```

At this point, I consider what an `Item` should expose to our `LineItemGenerator`.

- Items have attributes
- Attributes have values, which implies they should have names as well.

Given that understanding, I can implement `LineItemGenerator` as:

```
class LineItemGenerator
  def initialize(item)
    @item = item
  end

  def attribute_values(*attribute_names)
    @item.attributes.select { |attribute| attribute_names.include?(attribute.name) }.map(&:value)
  end
end
```

At this point, there are two contracts which need to be fulfilled:

1. Item needs to implement `#attributes`
2. `item.attributes` needs to return a set of objects which respond to `#name` and `#value`

Now, let's think from an item's perspective.
 - An item has many attributes (eg. name and style). 
 - The relevant attribute values may be defined on the `Item` object or be delegated to other objects.

Contract 1 is trivial to fulfil:

```
class Item
  attr_reader :attributes
end
```

Contract 2 is a bit more flexible as it can be fulfilled on either Item or the individual attribute classes. I'd implement it on `Item` if an Attribute is not a first class concern in the application.

```
class Item
  attr_reader :attributes

  Attribute = Struct.new(:name, :value)

  def initialize(name:, style:)
    @attributes = [
      Attribute.new(name: :name, value: name),
      Attribute.new(name: :style, value: style) 
    ]
  end
end
```

If some other part of the system needs to interact with an Attribute as a first class concern:

```
# TODO: DRY up using inheritance or modules
class Style
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize value:
    @value = value
  end

  def name
    :style
  end
end

class ItemName
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize value:
    @value = value
  end

  def name
    :name
  end
end

class Item
  attr_reader :name, :style, :attributes
  def initialize item_name:, style:
    @name = item_name
    @style = style

    @attributes = [@name, @style]
  end
end
```

Comment: Why an array of `Attributes` instead of a hash of with name-value key-value pairs?

Comment: @mbigras A hash requires users of `#attributes` to know that this returns a primitive data structure, and puts the responsibility of parsing the data structure on to the caller. An `Attribute` object is also easier to extend (eg. add formatting methods, etc.).

Comment: In fact, you could return an `AttributeList` instead of an `Array`, which might be a more intuitive place to extract `attribute_values` (eg. `item.attributes.values(names)` ). And then we go full cycle by delegating that back to `item.attribute_values` if the rest of your application doesn't care about the concept of an `Attribute`. ;-)